# Output file keeps being created even when input file doesn't exist? ****EDIT****

Tags: c++, fstream, status

I am trying to write a program that moves the first line of a file into a new file. My goal is for the new file to not be created if the input file does not exist. I get it to read `.good()` so I get the message that the input failed. However, I cannot get the new file to not be created.

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
        fstream inFile;
        fstream outFile;;
        string fileName("");
        string destName("");

        cout << "Please enter file name: ";
        cin >> fileName;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Please enter file name of destination: ";
        cin >> destName;
        cout << endl;

        inFile.open(fileName, ios::in);
        outFile.open(destName, ios::out);

        getline(inFile, fileName);

        if (inFile.good() != true) { 
                cout << "?Unable to input file!\n" << endl; 
                return 0;
        }   

        else {
                outFile << fileName << endl;
                return 0;
        }   

        if (outFile.good() == true) {

                cout << "?File '" << destName << "' already exists!\n" << endl;
                return 0;
        }   

        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();

        return 0;
}
```

Can anybody help?

Thank you in advance.

Thank you for the help from earlier,

*****EDIT*****

I am curious now though. If the output file already exists, I want to make an error statement saying so. However, if the file exists or doesn't exist, I am still getting an error. I tried to move the outFile.open to the bottom so that the file is created before the check but it still says it already exists?

```
int main()

{
        fstream inFile;
        fstream outFile;;
        string fileName("");
        string destName("");

        cout << "Please enter file name: ";
        cin >> fileName;
        cout << endl;

        inFile.open(fileName, ios::in);

        getline(inFile, fileName);

        if (inFile.good() != true) { 
                cout << "?Unable to input file!\n" << endl; 
                return 0;
        }   

        cout << "Please enter file name of destination: ";
        cin >> destName;
        cout << endl;


        if (outFile.good() == true) {

                cout << "?File '" << destName << "' already exists!\n" << endl;
                return 0;
        }   

        outFile.open(destName, ios::out);    
        outFile << fileName << endl;


        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only open the destination filestream when you are about to write to it, otherwise the file will get created anyways.

Comment: `outFile.open(destName, ios::out);`  Look at your code.  This creates the output file.

Comment: Ahh, no wonder. Thank you guys! I'm just in an intro to C++ class so I appreciate the teachings.

Comment: Top hit on Google gives you your answer to the second question and you don't even need to click on the result. https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%2B%2B+fstream+good Welcome to StackOverflow but please try harder with your research before asking. (PS I'm not a C++ guy, I just googled this to see if I could find the result, if I can you can!) Give http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask a read as well, I did when starting out and now the answer I get are much better. :)

Comment: Sorry about that. I had come across that earlier and was confused about what I had read. I will re-read it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the open call of the output file to after the input file check.

Something like this:

```
int main()
{
        fstream inFile;
        fstream outFile;;
        string fileName("");
        string destName("");

        cout << "Please enter file name: ";
        cin >> fileName;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Please enter file name of destination: ";
        cin >> destName;
        cout << endl;

        inFile.open(fileName, ios::in);

        getline(inFile, fileName);

        if (inFile.good() != true) { 
                cout << "?Unable to input file!\n" << endl; 
                return 0;
        }   


        outFile.open(destName, ios::out);
        outFile << fileName << endl;`enter code here`        

        if (outFile.good() == true) {

                cout << "?File '" << destName << "' already exists!\n" << endl;
                return 0;
        }   

        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();

        return 0;
}
```